# How to Navigate to another HTML and pass the values from previous HTML Page in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have two HTML files in my project. Login screen and Welcome Screen. 
When user enters the username/password and clicks Login button, should navigate Welcome screen with the message "Welcome to DemoWorld" + userName. 
How can i navigate from login.html to WelcomeScreen.html page? 
How can i pass the valuefrom user name text filed to WelcomeScreen? 
Please help me.

LoginScreen.html

```html
<html ng-app="loginModule">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BestBuy</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/login.css" />
 <script src="D:\Desktop\Download\angular.js"></script>
 <script src="D:\Desktop\Download\angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "app/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="loginController">
<img id="logo"/>
<div class="container">
 <section id="content">
  <form action="">
   <h1>{{"Login"}}</h1>
   <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model = "username" placeholder="Username" id="username" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="password" ng-model = "password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <button type="button" id="btnLogin" ng-click="onClickLogin()">Login</button>
    <a href="#">{{"Lost your password?"}}</a>
    <a href="#">{{"Register"}}</a>
   </div>
  </form>
 </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginScreen.js

```
angular.module('loginModule', [])
   .controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'myservice', '$window', '$location', function($scope, myservice, $window, $location) {
        $scope.username = myservice.userName;
        function onClickLogin() {
            myservice.userName = this.username;
            console.log("click" + myservice.userName);
            //$window.location.href = "HomeScreen.html";
             $location.path( 'HomeScreen' );
        }

        $scope.onClickLogin = onClickLogin;
   }])
   .controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'myservice', function($scope, myservice) {

        $scope.homeHeader = "Welcome to BestBuy";
        $scope.welcomeUserMsg = myservice.userName;
        $scope.myservice = myservice;
        console.log("homeController" + JSON.stringify($scope.myservice));
   }])
   .service('myservice', function() {
        var getUserName = this;
        getUserName.userName = "";
    });
```

WelcomeScreen.html

```html
<html ng-app="homeModule">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BestBuy</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/home_screen.css" />
 <script src="D:\Desktop\Download\angular.js"></script>
 <script src="D:\Desktop\Download\angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "app/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="homeController">
<div id="header">
 <label> {{welcomeUserMsg}} </label>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <section id="content">
  <form action="">
   <h1>{{homeHeader}}</h1>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <img src="http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5674/5674002_sc.jpg">
      <br><label> Bookmark Title</label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <img src="http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5674/5674002_sc.jpg">
      <br><label> Bookmark Title1</label>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <img src="http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5674/5674002_sc.jpg">
      <br><label> Bookmark Title2</label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <img src="http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5674/5674002_sc.jpg">
      <br><label> Bookmark Title3</label>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

homeScreen.js

```html
angular.module('homeModule', [])
    .controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'myservice', function($scope, myservice) {
   
   $scope.homeHeader = "Welcome to BestBuy";
   $scope.welcomeUserMsg = myservice.userName;
   $scope.myservice = myservice;
   console.log("homeController" + JSON.stringify($scope.myservice));
    }])
```

Comment: simply create a service that will share a data

Comment: Post the data in a form using $http?

Comment: i have created a service but it doesnt work.

Comment: How to post the data using http?

Comment: In controller use $scope.myservice =myservice;  and in html ng-model="myservice.userName" and ng-model="mysevice.password"

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. It works in Login.html page. But how can i pass the same value to homeController which is different module and different controller? How can i navigate to WelcomeScreen.html and pass the same to homeController? Please help

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you are actuaaly refreshing the page. When you refresh the page all modules, controllers and services are intialized and data is lost.
You need something that could persist the data.

For navigation you can uncomment the line

```
$window.location.href = "HomeScreen.html"
```

You can use angular-local-storage.js.

Inject this in your module. Add dependency in controllers too.
You can add data to it following way:

```
localStorageService.add('key', value);
```

You can get data following way:

```
localStorageService.get('key');
```